# How do I say that a university has accepted my application for a course or programme?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

When I google "I have been admitted to" I get a few hits such as the following:

> "I have been admitted to the Institute for Orthodox Christian Studies."

> "I have been admitted to the economics PhD programme at Boston College."

Still, I don't get more than a few relevant hits on UK pages, and I get no hits at all when I google "I have been admitted to a course" and "I have been admitted to the university". Consequently, I suspect that in English you use a different verb for this, instead of "admit", but I can't think of what this would be.

So, now my question is: what would be the appropriate way to say that the university has accepted my application for a course or programme?

Comment: Why can't you use the 'accept' in the question title? Also, your sentences are an inverted form of "The Institute for Orthodox Christian Studies has accepted my application."

Comment: @WeatherVane Because saying "The XX University has accepted my application for a course" is much clumsier than just saying "I have been PARTICIPLE to a course". I guess I could perhaps just say "My application for a course has been accepted"... but is that the idoimatic way of saying it in English? To my foreign ears it sounds like an odd way of putting it/that there must be a more idiomatic way of saying this?

Comment: *Admitted* is a perfectly good word, although one is usually admitted to a school or a program, not a specific course.  A course is usually something like "Mathematics 101", and is part of a program.

Comment: @stangdon Thank you! I wonder why I get so few relevant hits even when I search only for "I have been admitted to" then? Oh well. Funny what you say about courses – it seems then that it's not really a language issue, but rather a matter of different systems. In my own country it is very common to apply for and be admitted to (!) individual courses just as well as to whole programmes :)

Comment: @Gerda When I search "I have been admitted to the university" (at Google.com, with quotation marks, in the Brave browser) I get "about 336,000 results". Google is notorious for providing inconsistent search results. (In fact, I was just discussing this within the past day for another ELL question.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Haha, yeah, it's weird, isn't it? Then again, I have restricted my search to UK pages only, since I don't want an endless number of hits from pages written by other non-native speakers, so that may be part of the explanation...

Comment: @Gerda Oh, when you wrote "UK pages", I didn't realize that that applied to the second half of that sentence, too. In any case, it is valid, as Stangdon mentioned; I have no idea why there are so few UK results.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan My fault for not being very clear! Thanks for confirming that admitted works though :)

Comment: @Gerda Very wise not to look at U.S. pages. Very few native speakers of English there. But the frequency of “admitted to” there is rather high according ngram. Probably immigrants writing books. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=admitted+to%2C+accepted+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: In informal American English, you would often use the phrase "got into"; you would say that you *got into* the university or course in question. I'm not sure if that usage is common in the UK.

Comment: @alphabet -  Yes, it is. I would say _accepted by_ when you know you have a place there, but not _admitted to_ until you are actually there.

Comment: @JeffMorrow :)) The reason I use UK pages is (i) because I can only choose one region (or at least I haven't been able to figure out how to choose more than one), and (ii) because I'm required to use British English rather than American English, and (iii) because I'm thinking that if something is reasonably common/ok to say, it should turn up on UK pages as well. I'm not specifically **avoiding** US pages. And either way, when I google US pages I still only get three measly hits for "I have been admitted to a course", and no hits at all for "I have been admitted to a programme", so...

Comment: @KateBunting Interesting! I'm wondering whether that (that you would only use "admited to" once you're actually there) would be because of the other meaning of "admit", as in "admitted to hospital"?

Comment: @Gerda (1) If you had said originally that you were prohibited from using American English, I never would have bothered you, but, in that case, it was rather misleading to quote something about Boston College, an American institution. (2) Has it occurred to you that you may be worrying about a cultural issue rather than a linguistic one? The threshold question is whether British universities generally require formal admission to a “course.” If they do not, then it is hardly surprising that you can find few references to such a process.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong - I had just assumed that _admitted to university_ meant 'received there as a student'. In the UK we tend to say _I've been accepted by, I've got into_ or _I've got a place at X University_.

Comment: @JeffMorrow (1) Oh, you're not bothering me at all!! My fault for not being clear from the start. As for the quote, it was one of the few hits I had when I searched **UK** pages; I didn't even register that itreferred to an **American** institution (which was obviously sloppy of me)! (2) Indeed it has – see the fourth comment above :) Then again, that still doesn't explain why I don't really get any hits for "admitted to the university" or "admitted to a/the programme" either...

Comment: @KateBunting Oh – so it was actually that sense of "admitted" you were referring to! But... hm... the admissions office at a university deals with applications and accepting students, rather than with actually receiving the students, don't they? Or have I completely misunderstood this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at ngram, there seem to be plenty examples of

> admitted to X

where X is the name of a university and even more of the less specific

> admitted to university

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=admitted+to+Oxford%2C+admitted+to+Cambridge%2C+admitted+to+university&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: Thank you! I have to admit I'm not really used to using ngram – but this seems to be a much more reliable tool than simple google searches, so thanks for the eye-opener as well :)

Comment: Be very careful with ngram. Context matters, and ngram has no idea what context means. Ngram is a tool, not an oracle.

Comment: Thanks for the warning – I'll keep it in mind :)